# I want to create springboot APIs in which I have to login as an Admin and retrieve the access token then validate it to get user data.(Using Keycloak)

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I want to create springboot APIs to login as an admin, retrieve access token then validate it to get user data. The problem is i'm not able to add dependency for `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` and it says

> Provides transitive vulnerable dependency maven:org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.33

Please provide me the steps which can help me to create APIs.

Comment: Which version for each dependency? What "says" that?